# sp_OAMethod fails when creating Excel; insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' works

Tags: sql-server, excel

Good day - I have used the code posted in https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-excel-workbench/#first for writing an Excel spreadsheet from Sql. This worked on my local machine, but not on the 64-bit server to which I deployed the code.

I can run a query such as the following via Sql Server Management Studio, and it will write to a spreadsheet:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Excelwork\testing2.xlsx;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') select ServiceStationInspectionID from [CriticalFailItemCount]
```

If I call the spDMOExportToExcel proc, however, it fails on the statement   `EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'Excel.Application', @objExcel OUT`.

Can anyone perhaps suggest anything that might help? I have seen numerous posts, some suggesting folder permission issues; I am not sure why I can write to a folder running the query directly in SSMS but when running a proc in SSMS I get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this:
IMEX=1;HDR=YES;

See the examples here.
http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion, but sadly it did not help. I have tried practically every suggestion I can find on the various forums, but to no avail. I now changed my stored proc from using the spDMOExportToExcel proc and I just use the "insert into openrowset" command directly in the proc, and that works. Now, however when I run that same proc as a job in Sql Agent, it fails again, as it cannot create the Excel application. I am about to give up - I cannot believe Microsoft makes it so difficult to export from SQL.....

Comment: Ok - an update. The proc with the "insert into openrowset" command now works; what I had done was I have saved my original proc under a different name, and once I had it running in SSMS I tried running it as a job via SQL Agent, but had neglected to update the name of the proc in that job. So, to cut long story short, I could not call the spDMOExportToExcel proc from within my proc, but I can use the insert into openrowset from my proc, so that will have to suffice. Thanks again for your response.